# How do I stop endlessly playing SpriteKit emitter?

Tags: sprite-kit, skemitternode

I am trying to stop emitter playing endlessly in my Sprite Kit project. The Lifetime setting is set to `Start=1` and `End=0` and it shows correct result that I want (emits only once).

Problem comes when I call it in update method it keeps emitting endlessly, I tried using `removeFromParent` and `removeAllAction` but no luck. Can you please help me with the solution here?

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

    [self updateheartPositionFromMotionManager];
    [self matchIt];

    if ( _heart.position.x == 512 && _heart.position.y == 484 ){
        SKEmitterNode *emitter =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sparkly" ofType:@"sks"]];

        emitter.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,               
                                       CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+100);;
        emitter.name = @"exhaust";
        emitter.targetNode =_heart;
        [self addChild:emitter];

    }else{

        [self removeFromParent];
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove it from the update method.

Comment: So if `_heart`'s position matches, you create an emitter. Seems ugly to me, there's a real chance you're creating 60 emitters a second here. Like @akashg says, remove the creation from you update method. I recommend you take a look at the SKEmitterNode's property [`numParticlesToEmit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKEmitterNode/numParticlesToEmit).

Comment: I knew I am doing something different. Let me give a try today and update my results

Answer (score 0):

//step 1 take a global variable 
   @property BOOL sparklyAdded; in your .h file

inside init or instance method of your .m file

sparklyAdded=FALSE;

-(void)particleAdded
  {

}

-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

```
  [self updateheartPositionFromMotionManager];
  [self matchIt];

 if (( _heart.position.x>= 512 && _heart.position.y=< 484 ) && !sparklyAdded){
     SKEmitterNode *emitter =  [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:
              [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sparkly" ofType:@"sks"]];

     emitter.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2,               
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+100);;
     emitter.name = @"exhaust";
     emitter.targetNode =_heart;
     [self addChild:emitter];
     sparklyAdded=TRUE;

  }else{

    [self removeEffect];
 }
```

}

```
-(void) removeEffect
```

{
      [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"exhaust" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)         {

```
    [node removeAllActions];
    [node removeFromParent];
     sparklyAdded=FALSE;
}];
```

}

//remember few thighs while adding particle 
1) they are expenisive cpu call so add and remove them only once from update loop

Comment: Thanks a lot for your expert comments, I will try this today evening and post my results.